# Location Code in Url - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm creating a directory for multiple locations for example, USA, UK and Canada.

I want something like this www.example.com/US and www.example.com/UK, www.example.com/CA

When someone visits www.example.com/US i want to list all listings under USA location. Similarly for other locations. For this i have a single database and multiple laravel installation for each country. (I'm new to laravel so do not know how to do this. I'm trying something on my own with my knowledge.)

I have added a prefix to the routes so that it adds the country code in the URL

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'USA'], function(){
  Route::get('/', 'Frontend\PagesController@index')->name('welcome');
});
```

When i visit www.example.com it shows page not found. However when i visit www.example.com/USA it works all fine.

I have two questions here.
1. Is this the right way to do it? Or are there any other methods with single installation like locales are handled.
2. How to use the default url as www.example.com/country-code-of-user (Auto Detect). I made a dropdown to change the country.

The first question is a general question which i wanted to check here with senior programmers. The later question is about the error im receiving "Page Not Found" which i want to solve.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have you got user country then you can redirect user to the proper url using some code like as :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/USA');
});

// OR you can use any controller method to get conditional country redirection

Route::get('/', 'User@redirectTo')

//...with method
public redirectTo()
{
    // if some condition
    return redirect('/USA');
    // else redirect to CA, UK and so on..
}
```